# Is it possible to create a FILE object (stream) in RAM?

Tags: c

Is it possible to create a FILE object in RAM as a kind of virtual memory? I already read on many sites, but all sites stated that C FILE streams always use real files on a disk. I would like to create a FILE object in RAM.

Do I miss some fundamental logic?

Here is my approach, but instead of using the tmpfile() method, which actually creates a real file on disk, I would like to create a file in RAM.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *buffer = tmpfile();
    int c = '\n';
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        fputc(c, buffer);
    }
    while(c!='\n');
    
    rewind(buffer);
    c = '\n';
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(buffer);
        fputc(c, stdout);
    }
    while(c!='\n');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: POSIX 2008 added `fmemopen()` and `open_memstream()` which you might look into.

Comment: How do you plan to use this in-memory file after it's created?

Comment: @dbush I would like to add massive amounts of bitmask manipulations to raw bitmap data. Some kind of graphic effect.

Comment: You say `which actually creates a real file on disk,` that's not true. It creates a file on the *filesystem*, but actually is under /tmp- which in turn is in RAM, not on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the base C language itself, there is no such functionality. The closest is `tmpfile`, which is specified in such a way that good implementations could have the "temporary file" it gives you live entirely in memory and never touch nonvolatile storage ("disk").

POSIX (2008 edition and later) standardizes `fmemopen` (allowing fixed-size memory buffers to be accessed as files for read and write) and `open_memstream` (allowing write-only generation of a string/byte buffer via stdio output functions) which are explicitly operating on memory, not an actual file, but they're more specialized. I would tend to prefer `tmpfile` for most uses still.